# Excel - formula : pointwise operations?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does excel provide pointwise operations (multiplications, additions, ...) ?

[image]

In columns A and B, I have numbers.
In each cell of column C, I have a formula `" C[1234] = A[1234] * B[1234] "`.
In C5, I have the sum of all the numbers above : `C5=SUM(C1:C4)`.

I try to understand if it's possible to insert a new line between line 2 and 3, then set `A3 = 5` and `B3 = 50` and get the C column updated automatically (update of C3 and C6). Is this possible ?

My understanding is that this could be possible if excel could provide pointwise operators (addition, multiplication, ...). I searched for it without success : does excel provide such pointwise operations ? In other words, can I put in the C column this kind of matlab-like formula `" C1:C4 = A1:A4 .* B1:B4 "` instead of `" C[1234] = A[1234] * B[1234] "` ?

If no, as I guess, is there a workaround ?

Franck

**UPDATE**

This is a simplification of "real life" case
In real life, I have columns A, B, C, D, E and I need `C = A .* B`,  `D = B .* C`, `E = C .* D` so I really need (cascade of) pointwise operations.

Comment: Hi Franck. Have you tried the sumproduct function? see [here].(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)

Comment: Not enough for real case : check out updated question

Comment: You can use array formulas, which are entered with `[SHIFT]-[ENTER]`.

Comment: Which version of Excel. Newer versions support dynamic arrays,

Comment: @JohnAlexiou : Excel 2016

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula `SUMPRODUCT` as follows and it will result in `300` without the need to perform a multiplication in each row first.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4,B1:B4) 'in cell C5 then C1:C4 is not needed
```

If you need the values in `C1:C4` too, you can put the formula `=A:A*B:B` in `C1:C4` and it will mutliplicate row wise then.

---

**To UPDATE**
Then your only option is using in …

- column C: `=A:A*B:B`
- column D: `=B:B*C:C`
- column E: `=C:C*E:E`

unless you are only interested in the sum of column E in the end, then you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A4,A1:A4,B1:B4,B1:B4,B1:B4)
```

[image]

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` could indeed work for this simple case, but likely not (or I don't understand how) for the real case : see question update (before to open this question, I tried to reduce the problem to it's minimal expression)

Comment: @FGH Well, then there is only this option if you need all the cascaded values. See my edit. Unless you are only interested in the sum of column E in the end then you can still use `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: @Peh : How do you set the whole column C  (= each cell of column C) to be ` =  A:A * B:B ` ? ` SUMPRODUCT  ` produce only one cell as a result (not an array)

Comment: @FGH like `Range("C:C").Formula = "=A:A * B:B"` but I recommend not to write a formula in **all** cells of column C because this will be over 1 million cells and slow down your sheet. Only write the range you actually need `Range("C1:C100").Formula = "=A:A * B:B"` for example.